# How to prevent the user from saving a file to any directory except one specific location?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on code (Excel 2016) to prevent the user from saving a file to any directory except one specific location.  I'm using the BeforeSave event as follows:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim NamePath As String
    On Error GoTo Final
'    If Saving Then Exit Sub
    If SaveAsUI = True Then
        Cancel = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        NamePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Name, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
        If NamePath = "False" Then Exit Sub
        If InStr(1, NamePath, "H:\SSV\WORK\Workcenter Safety Modification Tracking Files", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "You cannot save to another directory."
            GoTo Final
        Else
            Me.SaveAs NamePath
            GoTo Final
        End If
    End If
Final:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When I select File from the ribbon bar and then Save As, I end up here:
[image]

When I click the Save button my code assumes that I haven't already entered a new filename, so it prompts for a Save As name and location.  This works, as long as the user isn't using File|Save As.  Using a Save As Button from a Quick Launch or customized ribbon works.

My problem is that using File|Save As doesn't trigger the BeforeSave event until after you enter the new filename and/or select a new location and click the Save button on the File|Save As screen.  In the File|save as screen, I can already select one or both of these, but the BeforeSave event has no knowledge of this, it's firing just as if I had clicked on a Quick Launch button and hadn't already entered the new name or selected a new location. The user enters the new file name/location, clicks Save and is prompted again for a new file name/location.

I'm looking for one of two solutions:

1. A different way to limit where a user can save a file.
2. A way to pass the file name/location from the above File|Save As screen into the BeforeSave event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put a button on the sheet and force the user to use that exclusively.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If not DoingSave then
        Msgbox("You must save using the button")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When the user saves using the button, set `DoingSave` to True before saving and set it to False afterward.

Comment: They can still get around that by using any of the multitude of ways you can call a SaveAs.  The goal is to prevent them from having any way of doing a Save As unless the file is saved in the correct directory.  FYI - I have code that fires on opening that prevents the file from being opened if it's in any location but the correct to handle moving the file outside of Excel.

Comment: @FrankBall Actually that's not true; the code will run on SaveAs. The only to get around this is to edit the code. If I'm wrong, please tell me how. I couldn't do any SaveAs without triggering the Msgbox and Cancel.

Comment: Of course if macros are disabled then this won't work. Certainly not fool-proof, but it works.

Comment: My mistake. I see what you're doing now ( I missed the global variable part) and while it will work, my users won't accept this kind of solution.  They are pretty competent at Excel and are very used to File|Save As or using Quick Launch or custom ribbon buttons to carry out this kind of action, so having them have to use a custom button (which I personally think should be acceptable) would cause a mail storm of complaints.  If you'll throw in an edit on your answer, I'll pull off the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but when they select the new location it might change the current working directory - in which case using [`CurDir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/curdir-function) may help

Answer (score 0):

Application.GetSaveAsFilename() will return save as file path which you selected in File-> Save As.

C# code is below

```
Object obj = Application.GetSaveAsFilename();
if(obj != null)
{
   string filePath = obj.ToString();
}
```

In VBA

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```